# Laravel 5: not able to use pagination, I get error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render()"

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I am quite new to Laravel and started to play around with L5 and tried to paginate my data (from my HomeController method):

```
someMethod(){
   ...
   $messages = Message::paginate(50)->sortByDesc('timestamp');
   return view('home', ['messages' => $messages]);
}
```

in my home.blade view:

```
...
                        <div class="list-group">
                            @foreach($messages as $message)
                                @if(!$message->processed)
                                ...
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                        {!! $messages->render() !!}
...
```

I get the error below:

```
FatalErrorException in b706d42af4b0adc08aee8abb2fdf4ba9 line 105:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render()
in b706d42af4b0adc08aee8abb2fdf4ba9 line 105
```

I followed the logic from the Pagination doc page : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#basic-usage and https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your code. Try this:

`$messages = Message::orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')->paginate(50);`